# Inherited properties aren't bound during databinding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, interface

I have two interfaces, IAuditable and ITransaction.

```
public interface IAuditable{
    DateTime CreatedOn { get; }
    string CreatedBy { get; }
 }

public interface ITransaction : IAuditable {
    double Amount{ get; }
}
```

And a class that implements ITransaction, call Transaction.

```
public class Transaction : ITransaction{
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
    public string CreatedBy { get { return "aspnet"; } }
    public double Amount { get { return 0; } }
}
```

When I bind a list of ITransactions to a datagrid and use auto create columns, only the Amount gets bound.  The CreatedBy and CreatedOn are not seen.  Is there a way I can get these values visible during databinding?

Comment: IDK if the PropertyDescriptor might be a useful class to look at, as it can be used to "tell" binding about what properties are available for binding.  It has been a year+ since I've used it though so I can't say for sure if that's what you need or how to use it.

Comment: That's interesting. Binding Transaction objects works just fine, but binding as ITransaction does not. If you cast a Transaction to ITransaction, you still have access to all of the properties since ITransaction inherits from IAuditable, yet the binding algorithm does not pick up those properties. Interesting.

Comment: @Anthony - this is a common misconception of interface "inheritance".  Interfaces don't actually inherit in the same sense that classes do.

Comment: @womp, Yes, an interface has no way to implement "inherited" members. It's just interesting that, as a developer, you have access to the inherited properties when using the interface, but apparently reflection does not pay any attention to it. Thanks for the link in your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces do not define implementation - they only define required additional interfaces.

What this means is that any class that implements `ITransaction` is also required to implement `IAuditable`.  It does not mean that `ITransaction` defines the properties of `IAuditable` as well.

Therefore, casting something to `ITransaction` does not define it to have `IAuditable` properties.  It is simply casting to the contract that states "I can do all the methods in `ITransaction`".  The fact that anything implementing `ITransaction` is also required to implement `IAuditable` does not mean that `ITransaction` is defined any differently.

Phil Haack has [a great blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/10/interface-inheritance-esoterica.aspx) on this.

If you want to have all the properties inherited, you should be using an "Is-A" relationship (i.e. abstract classes), rather than a "Can-do" relationship (interfaces).